# WebP recommended settings for bulk conversion

Tags: webp

WebP seems to have an incredible number of settings you can tweak. That's great if you are converting images by hand, but is there a set of recommended default settings for WebP, or has Google published somewhere what settings they are using for Youtube?

See this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vJSCmIMIjI where they mention a 20% savings in file size. We'd love to see a similar decrease in file size without sacrificing (much) quality from our jpeg images, but I don't trust that I can just play with the settings for a little while and eyeball it to decide if I've degraded the quality too far...

Answer (score 1):

```
cwebp -preset photo -q 75 input_file -o output_file.webp
```